# Install ubuntu from USB drive

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb

I have a laptop with no cd/dvd drive. I want to remove win 8 and put ubuntu instead. I am not sure if there is UEFI in this laptop (its the cheapest). I don't want to buy a usb optical drive just for this. Is there a reliable and EASY way to install ubuntu from a USB drive onto my new laptop ?

I tried to install it on an external hard drive, but i saw no boot options. So, I got a new cheap laptop instead. Again, I am stuck. Is it really this hard to install ubuntu via usb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). it runs on most platforms or get the [universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) for Windows as a host.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which one is better and is actively developed ? I am trying unet for now, but its good to know.

Comment: Unetbootin can be a problem if you are installing linux on a system with EFI or UEFI - "Properly prepare your boot medium—Third-party tools for moving .iso images onto USB flash drives, such as unetbootin, often fail to create the proper EFI-mode boot entries. " LINK - http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/